# Playing audio from SWF Flash Player in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, flash, playback

I'm currently making an iOS application where you can search a song. You will then be given a list of songs which you can choose from and then stream from the app. It uses a combination of  the tinysong API and I'm attempting to use a URL from Grooveshark combined with the songID given to me to play the song... E.g.

https://grooveshark.com/facebookWidget.swf?songID=13963

I've already had a quick look at this post: [How can i share a grooveshark music url to facebook with the music widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521264/how-can-i-share-a-grooveshark-music-url-to-facebook-with-the-music-widget)

but I was wondering if I could get more information.

What I want to do is play the audio from that link with a changing songID...

My Objective C code for this is:

```
//Opens the link of Url from first song and plays it
NSString *SongID = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"SongID"];
NSString *playString = [@"https://grooveshark.com/facebookWidget.swf?songID="     stringByAppendingString:SongID];

//Converts songURL into a playable NSURL
NSURL *playURL = [NSURL URLWithString:playString];

AVAudioPlayer *backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:playURL error:&error];
[backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
[backgroundMusicPlayer play];
```

But it isn't playing. What should I do to make it play? I know iOS can't play Adobe flash player and considering it is in a swf format, that's why I figured it can't play but I don't know much about flash and/or it in conjunction with iOS. So any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

If there is another way to access and play songs from a massive database of songs with their artists and albums too from objective C (like spotify API, but free), please comment as that may be another solution!

Thanks!